# duplicate push notifications

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

We have been using **APNS** on our app, our users are complained that they are receiving the same **push notification twice**. Our servers are sending only one push notification payload to Apple, the second push notification reaches to users after one hour of the first push note arrival.

Is any one facing the same issue?

Comment: Do you have the same device tokens twice in your database?

Comment: which one library you are using for interacting with server from iPhone application is it ASHITTP??

Comment: no, i don't have the same device tokens